# Search query error "Cannot query field \"search\" on type \"Query\"

Tags: jss, graphql

I'm trying to get data using GraphQL query with using search and get it when testing at /sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui window [image]- search really work, but when I look at the React component data using Chrome tools - here such exception "Cannot query field \"search\" on type \"Query\"." [image] 
I look at my GraphQL config and schema and **search** already included in Query type[image] 
[image] Other type of query work normallu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding GraphQL settings into the config file in jss project (in folder sitecore/config/{name-of-your-application}) and deploy this file to sitecore instance (cause I work in **integrated mode with JSS** - https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/graphql/integrated-graphql#integrated-graphql-in-jss-apps)